# jquery datepicker determine first shown date clicking next month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to get the first shown date of a datepicker when clicking on next (or previous) month.
The datepicker shows 2 months (eg november and december) and when i click on next month i want to trigger a function with the first date as a variable like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-next',function(){
  test(first_date);
});

$(function() {
    $( "#vak_kalender" ).datepicker({      
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: new Date(),            
        maxDate: new Date(volgend_jaar, 24,0),
        beforeShowDay:function highlightDays(date) {
        var timestamp = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()));
  var timestamp = timestamp/1000;
  if ($.inArray(timestamp, verhuurt) != -1){
               return [false,'verhuurt'];
            }
        else if ($.inArray(timestamp, gesloten) != -1) {
              return [false,'gesloten'];
          }
        else if ($.inArray(timestamp, wisseldagen) != -1) {
              return [true,'wisseldag'];
          }
        else{return [true, 'beschikbaar'];}
        },
        showWeek: true 
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
$( "#datepicker, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: 2 });
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-next',function(){
  var picker = $.datepicker._curInst;
  var date = new Date(picker.selectedYear, picker.selectedMonth, 1);
  console.log(date);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RdeGD/)**

**Edit**

You are using an inline datepicker, so the way you access the datepicker is slightly different. The following should work.

```
$("#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: 2 });
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-next',function(){
    var picker = $("#datepicker1").data("datepicker");
    var date = new Date(picker.selectedYear, picker.selectedMonth, 1);
    console.log(date);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fENnm/)**

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle, but not with my datepicker, added the datepicker in the question. I initialise it in a DIV, so thats the only difference i can discover

Comment: Are you using the same version of jQuery UI? If not can you tell me what version you are using?

Comment: I cant watch the code on my iphone, check the code of the page http://www.huurhulp.nl/verhuur/auto-s-en-personenvervoer/autobussen/friesland/test-met-commentaerene-40/

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar You are using the inline datepicker so it is slightly different. Look at the edit I added.

Comment: sorry for the late respons, but some other work in the house. But this is also not working, also not in the fiddle....